# How to search through multi layers nested objects by keys in js

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to search through multi layered nested object in javascript. The number of layers is dynamic.Not fixed.
Let's say I have an object like this.

```
       data={
            "_index": "sample_data_logs",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "lDMTgnEBbYNxp5GHN-gj",
            "_version": 1,
            "_score": 7.6343846,
            "_source": {
                "agent": "Mozilla/4.0",
                "bytes": 6948,
                "clientip": "172.3.128.226",
                "extension": "",
                "geo": {
                    "srcdest": "IN:BY",
                    "src": "IN",
                    "dest": "BY",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": 41.92076333,
                        "lon": -71.49138139
                    }
                },
                "host": "www.host.co",
                "index": "sample_data_logs",
                "ip": "172.3.128.226",
                "machine": {
                    "ram": 5368709120,
                    "os": "win 8"
                },
                "memory": null,
                "phpmemory": null,
                "request": "/apm",
                "response": 200,
                "tags": [
                    "success",
                    "security"
                ],
                "timestamp": "2020-04-13T11:05:05.551Z",
                "url": "https://www.elastic.co/downloads/apm",
                "utc_time": "2020-04-13T11:05:05.551Z"
            }
        }
       keys= ["_index","bytes","os","tags"];
```

And I have an array of key values to find or filter in data.
How can I do that?
Using lodash I have tried

```
_.pick(data_, keys);
```

I don't get the expected results which should be:

```
                   {
                    "_index": "sample_data_logs",
                    "bytes": 6948,
                    "os": "win 8",
                    "tags": [
                      "success",
                      "security"
                     ]
                    }
```

What is the best way of doing this? can it be done in vanilla js?

Comment: your question is not completely clear. is it guaranteed that each key in your `keys` list is exactly appeared once in your data?

Comment: yes it will appear exactly once in my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse your data recursively, like this:

**Explanation:**

We have a function `traverse` that takes:

- an object (called `data`),
- a list of keys (called `keys`),
- and an object that contains the current result (the found key/value pairs called `result`)

In the `traverse` function, we go over the first level keys of object data (using `Object.keys(data)`) and we check if each of them is in the `keys` list, and if it is then we add that key/value pair to the result and go to the next one.

But if it is not in the `keys`, then we need to check if that key is a nested object, so we do that with this conditions:

```
if (
  data[k] &&
  typeof data[k] === "object" &&
  Object.keys(data[k]).length > 0
)
```

- The first one (`data[k]`) is used to rule out `null` and `undefined`
- The second one (`typeof data[k] === "object"`) is used to check if the value is an object
- The third condition is used to rule out native objects like `Date`

And if it is a nested object, then we call the `traverse` (recursive) again

```js
let data = {
  _index: "sample_data_logs",
  _type: "_doc",
  _id: "lDMTgnEBbYNxp5GHN-gj",
  _version: 1,
  _score: 7.6343846,
  _source: {
    agent: "Mozilla/4.0",
    bytes: 6948,
    clientip: "172.3.128.226",
    extension: "",
    geo: {
      srcdest: "IN:BY",
      src: "IN",
      dest: "BY",
      coordinates: {
        lat: 41.92076333,
        lon: -71.49138139,
      },
    },
    host: "www.host.co",
    index: "sample_data_logs",
    ip: "172.3.128.226",
    machine: {
      ram: 5368709120,
      os: "win 8",
    },
    memory: null,
    phpmemory: null,
    request: "/apm",
    response: 200,
    tags: ["success", "security"],
    timestamp: "2020-04-13T11:05:05.551Z",
    url: "https://www.elastic.co/downloads/apm",
    utc_time: "2020-04-13T11:05:05.551Z",
  },
};
let keys = ["_index", "bytes", "os", "tags"];

function traverse(data, keys, result = {}) {
  for (let k of Object.keys(data)) {
    if (keys.includes(k)) {
      result = Object.assign({}, result, {
        [k]: data[k]
      });
      continue;
    }
    if (
      data[k] &&
      typeof data[k] === "object" &&
      Object.keys(data[k]).length > 0
    )
      result = traverse(data[k], keys, result);
  }
  return result;
}

result = traverse(data, keys);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  if (key === target) {// do somethings}
}
```

If the keys is equal to your need, you can perform your treatment ?

Hope it's help